# Can you prevent an Angular component's host click from firing?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-template

I'm creating an Angular component that wraps a native `<button>` element with some additional features. Buttons do not fire a click event if they're disabled and I want to replicate the same functionality. i.e., given:

```
<my-button (click)="onClick()" [isDisabled]="true">Save</my-button>
```

Is there a way for `my-button` to prevent `onClick()` from getting called?

In Angular you can listen to the host click event this way, and stop *propagation* of the event:

```
//Inside my-button component
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onHostClick(event: MouseEvent) {
  event.stopPropagation();
}
```

This prevents the event from bubbling to ancestor elements, but it does not stop the built-in `(click)` output from firing on the same host element.

Is there a way to accomplish this?

---

**Edit 1:** the way I'm solving this now is by using a different output called "onClick", and consumers have to know to use "onClick" instead of "click". It's not ideal.

**Edit 2:** Click events that originate on the `<button>` element are successfully stopped. But if you put elements inside the button tag as I have, click events on those targets do propagate up to the host. Hm, it should be possible to wrap the button in another element which stops propagation...

Comment: (click)="condition ? onClick() : null"

Comment: I want it to behave like a button -- I don't want the consumer of my component to have to check the disabled state first.

Comment: Does [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-vm9gqu?file=app%2Fmy-custom.component.ts) do what you want?

Comment: Close: I think [this stackblitz edit](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-dl7d5j?file=app%2Fmy-custom.component.ts) will be a little simpler for me. You're right we want to stop propagation of everything inside the host if disabled. If `<button>` is disabled you can't listen to (and stop) propagation of clicks originating from spans inside the button. But you can do it from another element wrapping the button but inside the host--as long as there isn't some part of the host you can click that's outside of the wrapping element.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You could do the following:

- Redefine the `click` event of the component, and emit this event when the button is clicked
- Set the CSS style `pointer-events: none` on the component host
- Set the CSS style `pointer-events: auto` on the button
- Call `event.stopPropagation()` on the button click event handler

If you need to process the click event of other elements inside of your component, set the style attribute `pointer-events: auto` on them, and call `event.stopPropagation()` in their click event handler.

You can test the code in [**this stackblitz**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-vm9gqu?file=app%2Fmy-custom.component.ts).

```
import { Component, HostListener, Input, Output, ElementRef, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-button',
  host: {
    "[style.pointer-events]": "'none'"
  },
  template: `
    <button (click)="onButtonClick($event)" [disabled]="isDisabled" >...</button>
    <span (click)="onSpanClick($event)">Span element</span>`,
  styles: [`button, span { pointer-events: auto; }`]
})
export class MyCustomComponent {

  @Input() public isDisabled: boolean = false;
  @Output() public click: EventEmitter<MouseEvent> = new EventEmitter();

  onButtonClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    this.click.emit(event);
  }

  onSpanClick(event: MouseEvent) {
    event.stopPropagation();
  }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**:

Since the button can contain HTML child elements (`span`, `img`, etc.), you can add the following CSS style to prevent the click from being propagated to the parent:

```
:host ::ng-deep button * { 
  pointer-events: none; 
}
```

Thanks to [@ErikWitkowski](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3423112/erikwitkowski) for [his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415692/can-you-prevent-an-angular-components-host-click-from-firing/49417360?noredirect=1#comment102625424_49417360) on this special case. See [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-imsmie?file=app/my-custom.component.ts) for a demo.

Comment: See my reply to you on the OP. This wouldn't stop events originating from elements inside the button from propagating out (the button click event won't fire if the button is disabled, so propagation won't be stopped).

Comment: The click event of the host element will not fire in that case either, as you can see when you test the stackblitz. The `pointer-events` style attribute prevents the host from catching the event.

Comment: I'll accept this answer. It can be made simpler depending on the specific use-case but the general idea is that if it's disabled you have to prevent any click event from ever reaching the host element.

Comment: This is a nice solution to prevent host firing the event. For me it was even more simple by add `$event.stopPropagation();` directly on the button element. `<button type="button" data-toggle="collapse" (click)="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed; $event.stopPropagation();"  appPreventDefault>`

Comment: Fantastic ! This solution works like a charm in order to disable conditionnally a custom Angular Component (which is not a "button", but is still clickable). Thank you !

Comment: NOTE: if you have a <ng-content> tag inside the button, it becomes a <span> and the problem will be back as now the span handles the click and propagates it back to the host, to solve you can add css `:host /deep/ button span {  pointer-events: none; } `

Comment: Consider the following full solution: https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-toqhjr

Comment: @ErikWitkowski - Thanks for the note and code sample. One small remark: according to [Angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/component-styles#deprecated-deep--and-ng-deep), `::ng-deep` is preferred over `/deep/`.

Comment: @ErikWitkowski - I updated the answer to account for your comment. Thanks again!

Comment: This is great but doesnt seem to work in ie11. Any solutions for that?

Comment: Just saying, this hould not ne the accepted solution. Setting "pointer-events" to "none" also disabled other things aswell like hovering-cursor. As already stated, stopping the eventpropagation sinde the component does NOT stop it on the outside. And having internal logic OUTSIDE of the component does not make sense. I think the cleanest solution in this case is to go with an alternative output called something like "clicked" and use only that one. The emit of this output can be 100% controlled inside the component.

Answer (score 3):

Catch click with early subscription.

Easy way would be to catch event on capture phase, but
there is some problem with capture catch in a Firefox (when event target is disabled, click event comes to host on bubbling phase, not on capture). So we have to add event listener in constructor (not on init) to be the first subscriber and to use stopImmediatePropagation on event.

```
@Input() disabled: boolean;

constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', this.captureClick, true);
}

ngOnDestroy() {
  this.elementRef.nativeElement.removeEventListener('click', this.captureClick, true);
}

private captureClick = (event: PointerEvent) => {
  if (this.disabled) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    return false;
  }
  return true;
};
```

Comment: thanks! This solution works for me but the accepted answer doesn't

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe there is a native way to prevent the event from firing, as supported by [this git issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9587) in 2016:

> The order of execution is red herring - the order in which an event on the same element is propagated to multiple listeners is currently undefined. this is currently by design.
>
> Your problem is that the event exposed to the listeners is the real DOM event and calling stopImmediatePropagation() on the provided event stops execution of other listeners registered on this element. **However since all the the listeners registered via Angular are proxied by just a single dom listener (for performance reasons) calling stopImmediatePropagation on this event has no effect.**

Comment: It makes sense that what I want is not possible if (click) on the component is an event listener on the element, but I was hoping it was more of a "default output" that I could override :(

Comment: @ryansilva I did try and solve this issue with some custom removing then custom re emitting of events via `HostListener` to unfortunately no avail. I hope you find a solution though as the functionality you propose sounds terrific.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native add and remove EventListeners. This is in no way a good solution when thinking in angular terms. Also, this won't work if you put `disabled` attribute in `button` as it will override eventListeners attached. A `disabled` class need to be used instead. (Or else wrap `button` in a `span` and use template ref `#btn` from it.)

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/my-button-prevent-event-vnatwu)

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnChanges, HostListener, Input, Output, EventEmitter, SimpleChanges, ElementRef, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-button',
  template: `<button [class.disabled]="isDisabled" #btn><span>hey</span></button>`,
  styles: [`button.disabled { opacity:0.5 }`]
})
export class MyButtonComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  disableClick = e => e.stopPropagation();
  @Input() isDisabled: boolean;
  @ViewChild('btn') btn: ElementRef;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges) {
    if(this.isDisabled) {
      this.btn.nativeElement.addEventListener('click', this.disableClick);
    } else {
      this.btn.nativeElement.removeEventListener('click', this.disableClick);
    }
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try stop propagation of the event in capturing mode (look at **true** as the last param of addEventListener calling and **window** as the listening object).

```
window.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
    let clickDisallowed = true; // detect if this click is disallowed

    if (event.target === this.elementRef.nativeElement && clickDisallowed) {
        event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
}, true);
```

And do not forget unsubscribe this listener.