# Angular prevent host click for custom button component with disabled input parameter

Tags: angular

A lot is written about this problem, but all answers suggests one or more of the following:

- `stopPropagation`
- `preventDefault`
- `return false`.

But non is working in my case. Here is [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-cb2ek8?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts).
When button is clicked, desired behaviour is that console shows:

```
click - button
stop
```

but it also shows

```
Click from app component - but it shouldn't happened
```

This click shouldn't happen (in `app.component`):

```
<my-button [disabled]="true" (click)="onClick()"></my-button>`

public onClick()
{
  console.log("Click from app component - but it shouldn't happened");
}
```

One solution is provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49417360/3170087). But, is creating another span element. Is this really the only option?

Also

> native add and remove EventListeners

doesn't looks as elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remove the `HostListener` and add a click listener for the `button` in `my-button` component.

Plus, you don't need the additional `this.click.emit()` since it's automatically going to propagate if `stopPropogation` is not called.

**Template**

```
<button (click)='onClick($event)'>{{text}}</button>
```

When the button is clicked, the `onClick` in `my-button` is called, based on some  logic you can either choose to emit or discard the `click`.

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-button",
  template: `<button (click)='onClick($event)'>{{text}}</button>`
})
export class MyButton
{
  @Input() disabled = false;

  @Input() text = "Click me";
  @Output() click = new EventEmitter();

    public onClick(event: Event)
    {
        console.log("click - button");
        if (!this.disabled)
            console.log("click emit");
        else
        {
            console.log("stop");
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
}
```

## [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-custom-button?file=src/app/app.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you named your EventEmitter as "click" which is the same name that Angular uses for naming the click event. So change the name of your EventEmitter from "click" to "clickEmitter" and this will solve your problem.

```
<my-button [disabled]="true" (clickEmitter)="onClick()"></my-button>
@Output()
public clickEmitter = new EventEmitter();
```

Comment: I don't like this idea. Developer could write `(click)` event handler on `my-button` because he forget to use `clickEmitter` and click will work even if it shouldn't.

Answer (score 0):

I recently had this problem and the easiest solution I found was to put a div around the button element and proxy the click calls from there:

```
@Component({
  selector: "my-button",
  template: `<div (click)="proxyClick($event)">
                 <button
                     type="button"
                     [disabled]="disabled"
                     mat-flat-button
                     [color]="color"
                 >
                     {{text}}
                 </button>
            </div>`
})
export class MyButton
{
    @Input() disabled = false;
    @Input() text = "Click me";

    public proxyClick(event: MouseEvent): void {
        if (this.disabled) {
            event.stopImmediatePropagation();
            event.stopPropagation();
        }
    }
}
```

I'm using Angular Material, it may be the cause why every solution "proxying" the click directly from the button wasn't working. I also only see this happening in Chrome.