# HTML element in button prevents disabled in the wrapper element

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular

**Fiddle**: http://jsfiddle.net/0o1mrapd/20/

**Angular stackblitz link**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fhtaki?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

I have a complex case which i need some enlightenment. (For angular developers, you can think the wrapper `div` as a host selector, `<my-button></my-button>`)

As you can see in the fiddle I have a disabled button with a wrapper div which has a click event.

```
<div onclick="alert('hey')" style="display:inline-block">
    <button disabled>
      <span>Click</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

What I expect is that when I click on that area, nothing will happen but alas I get the alert. If I remove the span element and put plain text inside the button, this works.

```
<div onclick="alert('hey')" style="display:inline-block">
    <button disabled>
      Click
    </button>
</div>
```

How can I make the div unclickable in this case? I found out that pointer-events: none does the trick but then I lose the curser-event which I need for accessibility

---

I stumbled upon this issue while creating a custom button component with an ng-content in Angular but then realized this is bigger than the framework.
Some links i checked:

[Can you prevent an Angular component's host click from firing?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49415692/can-you-prevent-an-angular-components-host-click-from-firing)

[Add CSS cursor property when using "pointer-events: none"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25654413/add-css-cursor-property-when-using-pointer-events-none)

[How to stop event propagation with inline onclick attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/387736/how-to-stop-event-propagation-with-inline-onclick-attribute)

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/9587

Comment: Replace button with div and use rule="button" for accessibility? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/Roles/button_role https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26402033/missing-click-event-for-span-inside-button-element-on-firefox

Comment: Can I ask why you put the click event on the div & not on the button?

Comment: @Wimanicesir Thanks for the question. The reason is in the framework that I'm using, the wrapper div is shipped as a blackboxed html element. So the user can attach the events to that element. I tried to demonstrate the usage in that scenario.

Comment: Did you try to redefine event `click` as suggested on one of the links you shared?

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner yep, I will create a stackblitz that demos the issue in an Angular environment as well.

Comment: @yurzui I created a stackblitz for the angular environment as well. If I make it a div, i will lose a lot of semantic attributes. I don't know whether i can replicate things like, autofocus and type="submit" for example

Comment: Yes, I have tried it myself. I can't think of a way to stop this. I can suggest something else. I've developed couple of `button` components myself. I think it is better to develop it as a directive. With this way, there will be no wrapper element in the DOM and you still get to apply some styling. Also, you will not need to provide every attribute `button` element takes.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner I also have that approach as Angular material does (which works nicely) but this is a different scenario in my case :-)

Comment: Then I'm out of options :) if you cannot find a solution, you could state in your docs that `click` event should not be bound by the user. They should subscribe to some custom event you will define within `my-button`. This would prevent the problem imo.

Comment: @BunyaminCoskuner yea I wanted it to be convenient for the user, that's why i didn't rename the (click) event. And yes I will be documenting it for sure :-)

Comment: I think the (click) event you're binding is the click of that my-button which not the click event of the templated button element.
Change the event name to btnClick and emit event via Output and it will work.
I hope it helps.

Comment: @NiralMunjariya for sure that will work, but still the (click) event would be usable

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this example will be useful

```js
function clickHandler() {
  console.log('Click');
}
```

```html
<div onclick="return false;">
  <button onclick="clickHandler()">
    Click
  </button>
 </div>
```

Comment: If you make the div disabled and put a span inside the button, the click event will still fire. I want it to be unclickable

Comment: Fire event on button because it has attribute `onclick="clickHandler()"`.
Replace this attribute to `disabled`.
If I know what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this css property to avoid click event be fired in the span tag. It could be a workaround.

```html
<div onclick="alert('hey')" style="display:inline-block">
    <button disabled>
      <span style="pointer-events:none;">Click</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you but as I've mentioned in the question: "I found out that pointer-events: none does the trick but then I lose the curser-event which I need for accessibility'