# Angular component: disable click event

Tags: angular, angular-components

I am creating a reusable component like this one:

```
<my-button [isDisabled]="isDisabled" (click)="click($event)"> submit </my-button>
```

I would like to disabled the click event when the property isDisabled is true, I tried something like that but it doesn't work.

packages/component/my-button.component.html

```
<button  [disabled]="isDisabled" #myButton>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

packages/component/my-button.component.ts

```
@ViewChild('uxButton') uxButton: ElementRef;
@Input() isDisabled: boolean = false;

this.myButton.nativeElement.parentNode.removeEventListener('click' , (e) => {
       e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

try like this

```
<button  [disabled]="isDisabled" (click)="btnClick.emit($event)">
        <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>

@Input() isDisabled: boolean = false;
@Output() btnClick = new EventEmitter();
```

Use `Output` and By default the button click event won't work if button is disabled. take advantage of it

```
<my-button [isDisabled]="isDisabled" (btnClick)="click($event)"> submit </my-button>
```

Comment: i want to do it inside the reusable component

Comment: I like your idea but it doesn't work ,  i can't see any @output in your code

Comment: sorry i have made a mistake. Updated the answer. `btnClick` is a output

Answer (score 16):

It is also solved by the following CSS:

```
# This prevents host to get a direct click
:host {
  pointer-events: none;
}

# This prevents the span inside the button to "steal" the click from the button
:host /deep/ button span {
  pointer-events: none;
}

# Now only the button can get a click 
# Button is the only smart enough to stop propagation when needed
button {
  pointer-events: auto;
}
```

And now you don't to pass down the click event manually like in other answers: You have the old (click) event back :D

```
<my-button [isDisabled]="isDisabled" (click)="click($event)"> submit </my-button>
```

In your custom component, you just need to pass down the disabled property:

```
<button  [disabled]="isDisabled" #myButton>
        <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

Also consider the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/template-driven-form-2-toqhjr) modified from [another stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49417360/3423112).

Comment: Take note that css `pointer-events: none` will disable other mouse events.  In turn, things like a tooltip will no longer work as there is no mouse event being fired.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to keep the legacy click event without using output. 
There is a combined solution based on the previous ones.

**my-button.component.html**

```
<button [disabled]="disabled">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
</button>
```

**my-button.component.ts**

```
export class MyButtonComponent {
  @HostBinding('style.pointer-events') get pEvents(): string {
    if (this.disabled) {
      return 'none';
    }
    return 'auto';
  }

  @Input()
  disabled: boolean = false;

 constructor() {}
}
```

**parent component where you will call your component e.g. *app.component.html***

```
<my-button [disabled]="isDisabled" (click)="onClickFnc()">
  <span>Save which not trigger click when button is disabled</span>
</my-button>
```

Answer (score 5):

You can check it on `(click)` attribute:

```
<my-button [isDisabled]="isDisabled" (click)="!isDisabled && click($event)"> submit </my-button>
```

Comment: This is not a good answer. If you're using your button in a 100 different places then that's a 100 extra checks.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to disable the click event of a disabled button in scss. This is what I added

```
:host {
button {
&:disabled:active {
      pointer-events: none;
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This can be archieved by using a boolean variable to check if some condition is true like so:

```
<my-button (click)="is_some_condition_true ? null : click($event)"> submit </my-button>
```

This condition could be for example:

setting the initial value of a variable like editMode, addMode or isDisabled in the component to false and then set this to true when the button is actually disabled.

*Ref: [how-to-disabled-click-event-or-any-event-if-condition-is-false-true-in-angular](https://jsbugpost.com/how-to-disabled-click-event-or-any-event-if-condition-is-false-true-in-angular/)*

Answer (score 0):

We can addeventlistener/remove based on the need using ElementRef/HostListener however the simple fix would be the below.

```
click(event) {
if (this.isDisabled) {
return;
}
......
}
```

Comment: i have to do it inside the reusable component, i used ElementRef but doens't work

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is in your code you have:

```
<my-button [isDisabled]="isDisabled" (click)="click($event)"> submit </my-button>
```

it should be

```
<my-button [disabled]="isDisabled" (click)="click($event)"> submit </my-button>
```

Comment: isDisabled is an input property for the reuseble componet

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `[disabled]` property as mentioned in the [documentation](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#property-binding--property-):

```
<button [disabled]="isDisabled" (click)="disableButton()">Disable button</button>
```

And then in your code

```
export class AppComponent  {
  isDisabled = false;

  disableButton() {
    this.isDisabled = true;
    // your code...
  }
}
```

Check the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-7nnnfp) for the demo.

Comment: i want to do it inside the reusable component

Answer (score 0):

First of all we need to ask ourselves why we want to create a new type of button component, when we already have a native one. It could be something like:

- Take advantage of some Angular helpers such as animations
- Disable the button during execution of some click handler.
- Progress indication.
- ...

If the requirement can be solved with a **native button (Solution 0**), stick with that. Otherwise, go on.

Two important things we need to know before creating a reusable
button component:

*K1* Only a limited subset of HTML elements can be disabled,
   https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics-other.html#disabled-elements. This
   means that a click handler is triggered even if the element is disabled.

*K2* In Angular, outside events can't be controlled from the inside
   inside. https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/12630

**Solution 1. Click handler as input**

To workaround K2 you could use an `@Input` callback instead of an
event binding. Then you have control of it from the inside, and
you even have access to the result of the callback on the inside. It
would look like:

```
<my-button [myClick]="doIt"> or with arguments <my-button [myClick]="doIt.bind(1)">

@HostListener('click') onClick(event) {
  this.myClick();
}
```

Since, you have complete control over the callback, you can just omit calling
it when it's `disabled`.

A problem that cries for this solution, is a button with progress indication. When you have complete control of the callback, the library button could start / stop animations of a progress bar or even block additional clicks by disabling it while in progress. Compare that to the progress buttons in this module
https://github.com/michaeldoye/mat-progress-buttons where you need to
start / stop animations for each instance of the button!

*Cons*: Non-standard looks. Your library users will be like why is that
callback an input and not an event binding...

**Solution 2. CSS**

You could try to workaround K1 with CSS `pointer-events:none`. It
would work on the surface, blocking user mouse triggered click
events. However, you can still click pragmatically on the
button. `myButton.click()` still fires when the button is 'disabled'.

*Cons*: 'Disabled' elements are still `click`able. Probably, not good for
your library users writing automated tests.

**Solution 3. Componentize native button**

For disable and events to work as expected, you need to apply the
component directly on the HTML button element. In Angular Material it looks
like `<button mat-button>`,
https://github.com/angular/components/blob/master/src/material/button/button.ts#L66

And it's quite simple:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'button[my-button]',
  template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
```

And using the it:

```
<button my-button (click)="doIt()" [disabled]="isDisabled">Save</button>
```

Now the click event is not fired when `my-button` is disabled.

*Cons*: Native button must be there, and `my-button` looks more as if it
were a directive than a component.

**Conclusion**

I would suggest to go with the solution that best fits the requirement, but not the CSS hack one.